# Show modal when [submit, action] button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make a modal appear to show Payment Status: Pending when the button is clicked, the form also uses it's action feature and opens a new window using target="_blank".

I want to open the modal and new window at the same time. 
I have tried using javascript, jquery but none of them showing the modal when I click on the button. When I load  modal on the page document ready, it works. But i don't want that.

**My code**

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="Loading_purchase_status" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Loading Payment Status</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                        <h4><i class="alert-ico fa fa-fw fa-ban"></i><strong>Loading your payment status!&thinsp;</strong></h4>
                        Current Status: Awaiting Payment...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#please_wait').fadeOut(7000);
        $('.itm_purchase_content').hide(0).delay(5000).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $('#paypal_submit').click(function () {
        $('#Loading_purchase_status').modal('show');
    });
    </script>
```

***Then my form with the button i want to show the modal when clicked :***

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $site_config->grabSiteSettings_manual($con, 'paypal_address'); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="username=<?php echo $username; ?>&product= <?php echo $name; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $site_callback; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $site_return_success; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $site_return_canceled; ?>">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="paypal_submit"
        style="vertical-align : bottom; margin-bottom: 15px; display: block; width: 40%; float:left; margin-left: 9%;">
    <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i>aypal
</button>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"
        style="vertical-align : bottom; margin-bottom: 15px; display: block; width: 40%; float: right; margin-right: 9%;">
    <i class="fa fa-btc"></i>itcoin
</button>
</form>
```

I want a button with the `id="paypal_submit"` to show modal when clicked, but also need to show the new window with the form action url

Comment: you need prevent form send event

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko What do you mean ?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @ErrorinException So where would this go ?

Comment: @Benza when you click on the button browser sends form data to server, you need change this behavior

Comment: You can change the button type from submit to button which will stop the form being submitted. If you need to submit the form after you can use JavaScript/JQuery to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the click function inside `document.ready()` like this :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#please_wait').fadeOut(7000);
        $('.itm_purchase_content').hide(0).delay(5000).fadeIn("slow");

        $('#paypal_submit').click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $('#Loading_purchase_status').modal('show');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default browser behaviour which is to submit your form by using [`event.preventDefault();`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/),

```
$('#paypal_submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#Loading_purchase_status').modal('show');
});
```

This will then prevent the form from being submitted as a result the modal will show.

**Note** - Ensure your event listener is in the `ready` event function before manipulating the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#please_wait').fadeOut(7000);
    $('.itm_purchase_content').hide(0).delay(5000).fadeIn("slow");

    $('#paypal_submit').click(function () {
        $('#Loading_purchase_status').modal('show');
    });
});
```

### or...

you could change the `button` type from `submit` to a `button`, this will change the behaviour without the `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default action on the button click and do the submit action manually.

to prevent the default action of prevent,

change this code

```
$('#paypal_submit').click(function () {
        $('#Loading_purchase_status').modal('show');
 });
```

to

```
$('#paypal_submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#Loading_purchase_status').modal('show');
 });
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or pen